# How to create a repository on F# for a DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, f#

So I need to have a repository to bind at an DataGrid View and I haven't made something like this before.
I made a type to have Informations from Textboxes

```
type BarcodeSamplesViewModel =
{
    TrackPosition : string
    TubePositionWithContent : string
    MaxTubePosition : string
    FixBarcodePart : string
}
```

and an Event to have the Informations

```
type ViewEventData = 
| SamplesClicked of BarcodeSamplesViewModel
```

How can I put the Informations in a repository(List) to bind at an DataGridView?

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, are you talking about the Winforms DataGridView?

Comment: Yes, it is a datagridview in winforms.